# How to use powershell to remove spaces from the beginning of a filename

Tags: powershell

I've been using the below to replace spaces in all the filenames and folders under the current directory location with underscores.

```
dir -Force -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace " ","_"}
```

How do I specify to only replace spaces if they are at the the beginning of the filename, eg the first character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem -Force -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName ($_.Name -replace "^ ","_")
```

Your post title doesn't quite line up with what you're asking.

There's also a syntax error in your example code (you're missing the period when trying to access the `Name` property of the PSItem `$_`).

None the less I hope this is what you're looking for. You were mostly there. The first parameter of `-replace` interprets regex.

Comment: Yes I worded this poorly. I want to change all files and folders under the current path beginning with a space to remove the space and replace it with an underscore.  I am trying your code now. So the "^" indicates the first character of the file or folder name?

Comment: @katama777 `-replace` uses regex matching. `^` matches the beginning of a string. It does not consume any characters.